# Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk NGINX

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

By default Elastic Beanstalk comes configured with an Apache loadbalancer. Is it possible to switch that out for NGINX? Thanks.

Comment: yes its possible - there's plenty of resources from google - check https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/09/14/replacing-apache-with-nginx-on-elastic-beanstalk/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible check this developer guide for setting the required.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html